# What are examples of good reference books on unsupervised learning?

Tags: reference-request, unsupervised-learning, books

I am looking for good introductory and advanced books on unsupervised learning. I have already read books like *Probabilistic Graphical Models* from D. Kholler and *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* from C. M. Bishop. I am also very familiar with the Ph.D. thesis of K. P. Murphy, on Dynamic Bayesian Networks.

I have read all of the above mostly for the probability aspects, not really the applications to AI and ML. I would like to know what are the good books (or references) for unsupervised learning, that focuses on practical exercises and examples instead of deep and abstract concepts.

Comment: I didn't find any freely available good book that focuses on UL, but [this paper/tutorial](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ul.pdf) could be useful. The book [Unsupervised Learning: Foundations of Neural Computation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/unsupervised-learning) (1999, edited by Geoffrey Hinton and Terrence J. Sejnowski) focuses on unsupervised learning algorithms for neural networks. However, I have not read it, so I don't know if it meets your needs. There are other books online, but I don't know whether they are good or not.